# Confused between K-Means and Hierarchical Clustering for 9 different categories

Tags: clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to classify 9 different species of elephants into clusters using unsupervised learning. I have the following data about them:

- Their height
- Eye Colour
- Sound they produce in decibel (dB)

I know there are 9 different elephant species in total. However, I am unsure which algorithm would work better. My dataset size is not too huge, so I was wondering if K-Means would be a general worse option here (as Hierarchical Clustering seem to give the same results on every run unlike K-Means).

Any guidance on this would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Eye colour is categorical, isn't it? How would you use that with k-means? Actually it isn't quite clear to me how you'd want to use that with hierarchical clustering either. Do you define a distance aggregating the three variables such as Gower's coefficient?

Comment: Lewian, yes, it categorical. They have some other datetime parameters too :)

Comment: There's no Gower's coefficient defined..

Answer (score 1):

**None** of them will give a meaningful result.

You attributes are **not comparable**. One decibel is not one eye color difference.

Results depend entirely on how you preprocess the data, and you can get pretty much any result you want (or did not want...).

Try to phrase your problem as an equation *first*. Do not try to solve it by trying out algorithms without a plan. You will see that your problem is not well specified, you do not *know* what you are solving.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of clusters already, k-means seems more fit than hierarchical clustering, because it tries to give the best possible solution, while HC uses a [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm), it doesn't matter much if it is deterministic.

However, k-means and HC are really comparable only if you use Ward method for HC, which is really just a hierarchical version of k-means. Single linkage, for instance, can give much different results.

Also, k-means and HC are not the only alternatives, EM clustering and k-medoids are two famous non hierarchical clustering methods, that provide some variations of k-means, with iterative estimating algorithms more reliable than HC, for a fixed k.

Comment: By Wald you probably mean Ward. "EM clustering" is not a method, you probably mean the EM algorithm for Gaussian mixtures (how to use that with eye colour??), but there are EM-algorithms also for various other models, so the term "EM clustering" doesn't say exactly what method you mean. k-means gives the "best possible solution" only according to its own objective function, which is not necessarily appropriate, particularly if separation between clusters is more important than homogeneity within clusters.

Comment: this is not a book on clustering, is an answer to the posted question. it's meant to give useful indications, not to confuse the OP, or to give her a master level understanding from scratch.

Comment: How do you use Ward with a variable such as eye colour?

Comment: jsut as the OP would most probably have: one hot encoding. that way a certain value is added to the distance between different eyed beasts, just like with Gower. you are making an issue of nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171837/kmodes-vs-one-hot-encoding-kmeans-for-categorical-data

Comment: Hi Carlo. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I'm solving a practice question for a lab in school, and I'm asked to make a logical choice between hierarchical clustering, and K-Means, and then write code for it. I understand K-Means might be a better choice as K is previously known and the clustering is more efficient. Any other reasons on why I should select K-Means over hierarchical clustering?

Comment: not really. In general practice, what you do is to try different methods and look for useful information anywhere, so you would try both; but in principle k-means classification is better, as it's expected to separate better the fixed number of clusters. (separation here is measured as sum of squared euclidean distances between clusters)

Comment: Thank you soo much Carlo!!!